# How to disable mouse and tracpad in vim?

Tags: vim, konsole

I want to disable mouse in my vim configuration.
I have tried these 3 settings in my vimrc file:

```
set mouse = ""
set mouse =
set mouse = a
```

but none of the solutions work.
I think it may be because of my terminal emulator, so tried some other terminals like terminator, guake, tilda but still the same behavior. Anyways, I use konsole.

Answer (score 2):

Clear `mouse` settings:

```
set mouse=""
```

Please note: no space around `=`.

PS. Your console still can react to mouse dragging but configuring it is a different story and offtopic for StackOverflow.